# Generic function for fetching different models in REST API

Tags: go

I am writing a library in Go for using the [Strava API](https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/). It's a simple API to expose the various objects (athlete, activity, and so on) that make up Strava's data. I am struggling to come up with a way that separates the mechanics of making a request so it can be reused to fetch the various different objects in the API. What I have so far:

```golang
type Model interface {
        Url() *url.URL
        Data() interface{}  // pointer to location of unmarshaled response
}

// an activity (run, bike ride, etc)
type Activity struct {
        Id                 int64     `json:"id"`
        Name               string    `json:"name"`
        Distance           float64   `json:"distance"`
        // ...
}

func (a *Activity) Url() *url.URL {
        return url.Parse(fmt.Sprintf("https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/%d", a.Id))
}

func (a *Activity) Data() interface{} {
        return a
}

// gear (shoes, bike, etc)
type Gear struct {
        Id   string `json:"id"`
        Name string `json:"name"`
}

func (g *Gear) Url() *url.URL {
        return url.Parse(fmt.Sprintf("https://www.strava.com/api/v3/gear/%s", g.Id))
}

func (g *Gear) Data() interface{} {
        return g
}

// a page of activities
type ActivityPage struct {
        AthleteId  int64
        PageNum    int
        Activities []Activity
}

func (p *ActivityPage) Url() *url.URL {
        return url.Parse(fmt.Sprintf("https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athletes/%d/activities?page=%d&per_page=%d", p.AthleteId, p.PageNum, perPage))
}

func (p *ActivityPage) Data() interface{} {
        return &p.Activities
}

type Client struct {
        hc    *http.Client
}

// error handling omitted
func (c *Client) fetch(m Model) error {
        data, _ := c.fetchUrl(m.Url())
        json.Unmarshal(data, m.Data())
        return nil
}

func (c *Client) fetchUrl(u *url.URL) ([]byte, error) {
        req := &http.Request{
                // omit access token
                Method: "GET",
                URL: u,
        }
        resp, _ := c.hc.Do(req)
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        return ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
}
```

The `Data()` pointer is needed because the `GET /athlete/activities` endpoint returns a list of `Activity`s, rather than a specific model. `ActivityPage` is therefore a bit of a hack — an object that carries the data needed to build the URL along with a place to put the results. For cases where a GET returns a model the `Data()` pointer is just the object.

With this code, I can do:

```golang
client := Client{}

activity := Activity{Id: 1234}
client.fetch(activity)
fmt.Print(activity.Name)

page := ActivityPage{AthleteId: 1, PageNum: 1}
client.fetch(page)
fmt.Print(len(page.Activities))
```

But this feels.. icky. I don't like partially constructing the object and passing it to `fetch()` to be finished off, or that `fetch` doesn't actually return anything except an `error` on failure. The `Data()` pointer is a hack.

AIUI, interfaces are a way to write code that can work with objects of different types, but I feel like I want the inverse — to have some code (a `Fetch()` method or something) that is inherited by all objects with a certain trait.

How can I make this cleaner? I realise this is kind of open-ended so I'm more than happy to refine what the exact question is as appropriate. Are there canonical examples of building a REST client in Go? (I haven't found anything compelling so far)

Answer (score 1):

this is a standard workaround typical for go, you pass a pointer to data you want to be modified by reflection, standard lib is built like that, you can at most make method to accept pointer to data and url directly to be more verbose and not interface. It will make it at least match cleaner what will get modified just from looking at api calls for user like:

```golang
func (c *Client) fetch(url string, responceBuffer interface{}) error {
        data, err := c.fetchUrl(url)
        if err != nil {
           return err
        }
        return json.Unmarshal(data, responceBuffer)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this'll certainly clean some parts up!